# Tests for Mean Reversion in a Portfolio Rebalancing

Tags: portfolio-management, mean-reversion, rebalancing

On a single time series one can run a [Dickey-Fuller](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Basics-of-Statistical-Mean-Reversion-Testing) test to determine if the asset is mean reverting or at least has been mean reverting during your sample.

Is there a way to test for mean-reversion in a portfolio of assets?  In other words is there a way to test if portfolio re-balancing would have offered statistically significant advantage?

Comment: You should read up on cointegration. Learn about the Engle-Granger test. If your portfolio weights are proportion to regression coefficients, then it should be similar to what you're talking about wrt testing for mean-reversion in a portfolio of assets.

Comment: Thanks @John.  If you expand in a full answer with a little more background, I'm happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two or more (I(1)) time series are cointegrated, then this means that you can find a linear combination of them that is mean-reverting. Thus, if you create a portfolio with weights that are proportional to this linear combination, then the portfolio returns will also be mean-reverting.

There is a large literature on cointegration and asset prices and many techniques to try to take advantage of this behavior in asset prices. For a small number of assets, you could fit a VAR or ECM. For larger dimensional problems, PCA is often used.